# Physical Significance of Frequency of matter waves

Tags: energy, particle-physics, momentum, frequency, matter

So, in our book there was an additional exercise part and this question baffles me:-
Q. Answer the following questions:-
The energy and momentum of an electron are related to the frequency and wavelength of the associated matter wave by the relations:
E=hν ; p=h/λ ;
where E=energy, h=Planck's constant, ν=Frequency, p= momentum, λ=wavelength.

But while the value of λ is physically significant, the value of ν(and therefore, the value of the phase speed νλ) has no physical significance. Why?

Now there was an answer given too but I can neither understand the question neither the answer... Please someone explain.

Ok so as someone requested I am going to put the answer given too:-
[image: imga]

[image: imgb]

Comment: Could you provide the answer as well? I agree the question is quite confusing/ambiguous

Comment: I did add it.. please check.

Comment: Please see my answer to the recent (22nd Feb) question "De Broglie wavelength derivation" It goes into the issues in some detail. I'd give you a link to it if I knew how to do links.

Answer (score 2):

The wavelength $\lambda$ is physically significant in the sense that you can directly measure it. You can perform the double slit experiment and that will directly tell you the wavelength of the particle.

To see why the frequency is not "physically significant" I will compare it to potential energy because the reasoning is similar (I put this in quotes for a reason, I will explain this). The potential energy of gravity on earth is defined as $U(z)=mgz$. You can also add a constant to the potential energy and still have the same equations of motion: $U(z)=mgz+U_0$. This is because the force is defined as the derivative of the potential $F=-\frac{dU}{dz}$. Because of this, the precise value of $U$ is not significant; only *differences* in $U$ are in important. To say that $U$ is not physically significant might be a bit of a misnomer. $U$ is very important in physics, it's just that the precise value is arbitrary since you can always add a constant.

Similarly, you can always add a constant to frequency (in the context of matter waves!). The frequency is still a physically significant quantity, it's just defined up to an arbitrary constant. This carries over to phase velocity since it is just frequency times wavelength. The group velocity is "significant" though, since you can measure this directly.

Comment: This is not quite correct because *dissipated energy* $Q^*$ or, if you wish, *dissipated work* is a well-defined quantity by itself. It is equal equal to the product of the irreversibly generated entropy $S^*$ and the absolute temperature $T^*$ at which *that* entropy is generated $Q^*=T^*S^*$.  In an irreversible process between a system and its environment $Q^*$ is the evolved heat, ie. the exergy loss.

Comment: @hyportnex I don't fully understand your comment. The quantity that you mention seems quite different than the (regular old) potential from mechanics. I think the quantity you mention is heat. I think it is usually defined as a "difference" quantity, i.e. as $\mathrm đQ=T\mathrm dS$, so I don't understand how its absolute value is important. I don't mean absolute in the sense that it is always positive but that you can't add an arbitrary constant.

Comment: When a small mass $\delta m$ falls in the potential $\phi$ of a gravitational field the work done is $(\phi_1-\phi_2)\delta m$ and it does not matter whether we have actually $\phi$ or $\phi+C$, C is arbitrary; the same for chemical potential $(\mu_1-\mu_2)\delta n$, and it is also the same when a entropy falls in a thermal gradient $(\theta_1-\theta_2)\delta S$ in thermal potential  $\theta$ that is the experimental reading of a thermometer. None of these thermal/mechanical/chemical/electric work processes have a need for an absolute potential scale. Not so the irreversible dissipation.

Comment: @hyportnex Oh I see. That's a nice example of where the absolute scale of a potential *does* matter. I still think my answer is correct because it only references a Newtonian potential, where the absolute scale doesn't matter

Comment: Since both dissipated work and entropy is well-defined, to correlate them one must have an absolute temperature scale with a energetically determined null point. My original comment was just amending to what you said about mechanical work to highlight that there is one place in physics of energetics in which an absolute reference point is given to us.

Comment: So physical significance is actually determined by the fact whether the quantity can be absolutely determined or not? Is that what you want to conclude?

Comment: @robustrimo For this question, yes. More generally speaking, physical significance is used in many different context and could mean different things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would do best to ignore this comment in your book; Personally, I even consider it wrong. We routinely talk about the energy of particles and that is a precisely defined quantity with no room for any arbitrariness or additive constant.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer after thinking a lot.
Our teacher had said that for electrons, E=hν was actually wrong, rather we should consider, E=0.5mv² , or, E=p²/2m so, this means if we use de Broglie's relation p=h/λ and put it in the energy of electron, we get
E=h²/(2mλ²) .
Thus we understand that for matter particles,ν has no physical significance while λ does have and since λ has physical significance, p also has... thus group speed=p/m and practically anything which can be related by momentum has physical significance as momentum can be related to wavelength.
(Like by the Davisson Germer experiment, we got to know about the wavelength of electron, which strikingly was in excellent agreement with the de Broglie hypothesis not its frequency! Right?)